# Where to find graphite rocks?

Tags: earth-history, rocks

Where to find graphite rocks?

I made researches in my city beach but I don't know where to find them.

Comment: Are you asking about geographical locations or geological settings? Also, what makes a city beach so special for graphite?

Comment: if you provide some more information like where you live and your general area it will help getting you better answers.

Comment: Do you want crystalline graphite, or any form of black carbon such as coal would do?

Answer (score 2):

> Graphite occurs naturally in metamorphic rocks or at the contact between an igneous intrusion and a carbonaceous body. Natural graphite deposits occur as lenses or layers of disseminated or massive flakes. What form the deposits take depends on the geologic background. One type called amorphous graphite, for example, is formed by the thermal metamorphism of coal.

https://www.earthmagazine.org/article/mineral-resource-month-graphite-0/